# CSS is ignoring background-image property

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have this div

```
  export const LIIconHolder = styled.div`
  margin-right: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #45cc8a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image:url(${check});

 `
```

`check` is an `svg` icon.

Somewhy the icon is not being displayed.The path is correct I checked it.

I checked inspect element and it is not reading it

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried bringing up the console and inspect the element?

Comment: go to page source and check the image url

Comment: Yep,In inspect element it is not reading the background-image property

Comment: When you say it's an SVG, is it a path to an SVG? A data URL? An imported SVG file?

Comment: I have svg in folder,And I'm importing it from there

Comment: Try to use `background` instead of `background-image`. Reference: [CSS difference between background and background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607999/css-difference-between-background-and-background-image#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=In%20a%20background%20property%20you,only%20allowed%20to%20add%20image.&text=By%20using%20background%2C%20you%20need,the%20background%20of%20the%20page.)

Comment: Could you expand the code snippet? At the moment we can't even tell if `url(${check})` is valid code as there are no backticks visible. It might need to be `\`url(${check})\`` depending on where it's being used.

Comment: Okay Sorry I will do it

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244463/react-svg-component-as-background-image-to-div) seem very similar, perhaps some of the answers there may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u tried to do this:

```
background-image:url(${({check})=>check});
```

instead of this:

```
background-image:url(${check});
```